# NSClassFromString custom class for cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have 50 more classes to load at runtime.  I know the class name as string.

I need to load all the classes from string name. like `NSClassFromString`, custom class of `NSClassFromString` for `cocos2dx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think it is possible, as methods like NSClassFromString requires reflection. If you wanna just configure what objects do you want to create on this launch, you can create some object that will create needed objects for given string keys(class names in your case).

Comment: I have a similar issue NSClassFromString returns empty.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63010211/couldnt-call-objective-c-method-from-cocos-2d-via-javascriptobjcbridge
Here is my question regarding the same. Could you please help