# Couldn't call Objective-C method from Cocos-2d via JavaScriptObjCBridge

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cocos2d-js

URL : https://github.com/cocos-creator/creator-docs/blob/master/en/advanced-topics/oc-reflection.md

Above is the documentation to call a Objective-C method from Cocos script

I trying to do the exact same thing, but I get the error

```
2020-07-21 15:56:01.094441+0800 hello_world-mobile[63684:4206926] TestingLogging.testingIntegration method isn't found!
[ERROR] (/Applications/CocosCreator/Creator/2.3.3/CocosCreator.app/Contents/Resources/cocos2d-x/cocos/scripting/js-bindings/manual/JavaScriptObjCBridge.mm, 418): call (TestingLogging.testingIntegration) failed, result code: -3
[ERROR] Failed to invoke JavaScriptObjCBridge_callStaticMethod, location: /Applications/CocosCreator/Creator/2.3.3/CocosCreator.app/Contents/Resources/cocos2d-x/cocos/scripting/js-bindings/manual/JavaScriptObjCBridge.mm:427
```

[image: Screen Shot 2020-07-21 at 4 05 36 PM]

.h class

```
//
//  TestingLogging.h
//  hello_world-mobile
//
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface TestingLogging : NSObject

+(void) testingIntegration: (NSString *) string;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

.m class

```
//
//  TestingLogging.m
//  hello_world-mobile
//
//

#import "TestingLogging.h"

@implementation TestingLogging


+(void)testingIntegration:(NSString *)string {
    NSLog(@"First ios call from cocos creator app %@", string);
}

@end
```

Script in cocos

```
onCameraClickHandler () {
    if(cc.sys.OS_IOS == cc.sys.os) {           
        var ret = jsb.reflection.callStaticMethod("TestingLogging", "testingIntegration", "Hello iOS")
    }
}
```

Could you please help me !

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C the colon is part of the method name. It's mentioned in the linked documentation

> **methodName** parameter in previous example is the OC method name in your class, take NativeOcClass as an example, we can see a method named

```
+(BOOL)callNativeUIWithTitle:(NSString *)title andContent:(NSString *)content;
```

> So the methodName should be callNativeUIWithTitle:addContent: which is the definition for this method, and don't forget the :.

The name of the method is `testingIntegration:`. Change the script to

```
var ret = jsb.reflection.callStaticMethod("TestingLogging", "testingIntegration:", "Hello iOS")
```

Comment: Have you worked with Cocos2d before? I wanted to know if we can import frameworks directly into the cocos creator IDE.

Comment: @KuldeepBhimte No, I'm not familiar with Cocos2d. Ask a new question please.

Comment: My questions are for Cocos2d. Anyway thank you for your answer